# Delayed data causes NullPointerException on OnCreate

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception

I have this activity that receives a JSON Response to display on UI. My request goes like this.

```
public void onClick(View click) {
    if (click == profBtn) {
       //this line creates the post request on my RequestHandler class.
       requestHandler.setURL(url);
       Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfActivity.class);
    startActivity(it);
    } else if....
```

This is my OnCreate method looks like in my ProfActivity

```
    TextView tv;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.prof_activity);

            //this command gets the data from the JSON Response from my mapper class.The JSON Response was converted to a HashMap.
            mapData=MapperClass.map;

    String value=mapData.get("key");
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(value);
}
```

The setText command causes NullPointerException. The making of request, receiving of the response, mapping of response into hashmap and passing the value of the map to the ProfActivity works fine. The problem here is the JSON Response is a bit late. The Oncreate method was already performed before the data to be displayed arrives.

Any idea how I can tell my activity to wait for the data?

Comment: @hichris123: What do you mean by doing it on AsyncTask? The Request is done in AsyncTask. I have a class that handles the request. "requestHandler.setURL(url);" is just a command that triggers the request on my RequestHandler.class.

Comment: please include code for requestHandler.setURL() also in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking your `ProfActivity` to wait, you should only start it when the request has finished. Put the startActivity code into the end of the `postExecute` method of your async task.

For me, I would also move the network request part into `ProfActivity` so that you do not need to access the result via a public variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using activity, then please use [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html), and put the parsing and setText part in `onActivityResult`.
Furthermore, [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) maybe a better choice.